# Graphic card Radeon HD 5450 or GeForce GT 210 with open source driver and HDMI

Tags: nvidia, ati, graphics, radeon, nouveau

I want to buy a new graphic card. I want to use the card with an open source driver (*Radeon* / *Nouveau*), but I need HDMI output. Which is the better choice, *Radeon HD 5450* or *GeForce GT 210*?

Comment: Just to point out you will not be able to run your pc in HD with the open source drivers so you will need the drivers anyway ps I like the nvidia cards but ATi is a bit beteer supported

Comment: What do you mean with: "you will not be able to run your pc in HD with the open source drivers "? I now run a GeForce 8400 GS with the nouveau driver and a resolution of 1920x1080.

Comment: For me I can only get SD resolutions on my Nvidia card with nouveau and have to install the drivers to use 1920x1080 maby this is a problem only with my card then I will have to look in to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I buy a [Radeon HD 5450](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ati_radeonhd_5450) graphic card, because the [Radeon driver supports TV-Out for this Evergreen GPU](http://wiki.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature#Feature_Matrix_for_Free_Radeon_Drivers). Furthermore this card should be a little [faster than the Nvidia pendant](http://www.hwcompare.com/376/geforce-gt-210-vs-radeon-hd-5450/).